# Getting current EasyButton state

Tags: leaflet, easybutton-plugin

I am using an EasyButton for showing a sidebar in a Leaflet map. Now I want to restrict the functionalities inside the sidebar in that way, that they only are accessible when the sidebar is opened. My plan was to ask for the current state of the easybutton, but I apparently don't know exactly how.

Here the code for the easyButton:

```
navi_button = L.easyButton({
 states:[{
    stateName: 'openSidebar',
    icon: 'fa fa-route',
    title: 'Navigation öffnen',
    onClick: function(control){
        sidebar.show();
        control.state('closeSidebar');
        }
    },{
    stateName: 'closeSidebar',
    icon: 'fa fa-route',
    title: 'Navigation schließen',
    onClick: function(control){
        sidebar.hide();
        control.state('openSidebar');
        }

    }]
});
navi_button.addTo(map);
```

Then it should follow like that (incorrect code):

```
if (navi_button.state() ==  openSidebar){
...[sidebar functions]...
}
else{};
```

Is there a way to get the current state of an easybutton?

Comment: I opened a GH issue asking for implementing that `control.state()` returns the current state: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/issues/87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get state of control in `navi_button._currentState.stateName` property, so your check would be something like

```
if (navi_button._currentState.stateName == 'openSidebar'){
...[sidebar functions]...
}
else{};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `===` in order to exactly check for equality?

Comment: Thank you! The approach I provided doesn't work though, but at least I can keep building on it

Comment: @Stefan Generally yes but in this case it's not really important.

Answer (score 1):

As of EasyButton 2.4.0 you will be able to use `control.state()` (without arguments) to retrieve the current control state.

Source: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/issues/87#issuecomment-453200962